# How can I make Google Talk client not to change icon colour when there is a new mail?

Tags: google-talk

I've marked the "disable all notifications" option but this seems to only control the pop-ups, not the icon colour change ... I **don't** want to be alerted to new emails but rather check the inbox when I want to... 
Please help :)

Comment: you'ld have to override the css/js that swaps the image...not something that is so easy to do on an https site.  if you find that it does it in js you can intentionally poison you cache with a javascript that is modified and set to never expire.  the site may still force a new one on you though....

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do this because I can't fathom why the color of the icon matters.  Why does this bother you?  (Also, this question probably belongs on webapps anyway.)

Comment: the color change bugs me because it serves as notification that there is new mail -which is what i don't want.

Comment: Also, as i specified I'm using the client (referring to the desktop client)- this does belong here rather than on "webapps"

Answer (score 0):

"disable all notification" should do ur requirement.
but Why don't you want to use it?

you can disable each notifications though?

Comment: As described in the question, I **am** using that. it doesn't do the trick

Comment: misread the Q,, :|